# Python - get subset from 2nd, to last element

Tags: python, dictionary, set

I have a bunch of strings, all on one line, separated by a single space.
I would like to store these values in a map, with the first string as the key, and a set of the remaining values.
I am trying

```
map = {}
input =  raw_input().split()
map[input[0]] = input[1:-1]
```

which works, apart from leaving off the last element.
I have found

```
map[input[0]] = input[1:len(input)]
```

works, but I would much rather use something more like the former

(for example, input is something like "key value1 value2 value3"
I want a map like
{'key' : ['value1', 'value2', 'value3']}
but my current method gives me
{'key' : ['value1', 'value2']}
)

Comment: Side note: don't use `map` as a variable name, since there is a built-in function with the same name. Also, in Python, "maps" are called "dictionaries".

Comment: In fact, don't use `input` as a variable name either. You guessed it: built-in function.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

That's because you are specifying `-1` as the index to go to - simply leave the index out to go to the end of the list. E.g:

```
input[1:]
```

See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/509295/722121) for more on the list slicing syntax.

Note an alternative (which I feel is far nicer and more readable), if you are using Python 3.x, is to use [extended iterable unpacking](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3132/):

```
key, *values = input().split()
map[key] = values
```

Comment: I believe you mean `key, *values` (the syntax of the Extended Iterable Unpacking which you link to). Also I believe you mean `input` rather than `raw_input` (non-existent in python3, which you claim to be writing in).

Comment: @ninjagecko Great catch on both of those, typo for the former, not looking at the copy/paste for the latter. Corrected.

Answer (score 2):

```
myDict = {}

for line in lines:
    tokens = line.split()
    map[tokens[0]] = tokens[1:]
```

Alternatively:

```
def lineToPair(line):
    tokens = line.split()
    return tokens[0],tokens[1:]

myDict = dict(lineToPair(x) for x in lines)
```